# Finding the point on an ellipse where a ray of light is reflected

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

For an ellipse with the equation $$\frac{(x-\tfrac{1}{3})^2}{\tfrac{4}{9}}+\frac{y^2}{\tfrac{1}{3}}=1\;,$$ at what point does the reflected beam cross the x axis if a ray of light is emitted from the origin at an angle of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to the $x$ axis.

I have attempted to begin this by working out a tangent line but has not helped me.

Comment: I've formatted the formulas in your post. It would be nice if you could do so yourself in the future. Have a look at [this quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/35416) and also look at the edit I made here, e.g. by editing the post again and then canceling the edit after studying the input format. Have you worked out where the ray intersects the conic? Have you worked out the tangent in that point? If so, what did you find? If not, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Is the denominator of the second fraction $1/3$ or $(1/3)^2$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie My guess is $1/3$ since that puts one of the foci at an interesting location for this problem.

Comment: Hint: where are the foci of this ellipse?

Comment: @amd The foci are (0,0) and (2/3,0) so the light is emitted through one of the focal points, since the ray of light always goes back through the other focal point does this mean the answer is simply (2/3,0)? and would this be the same for any angle?

Comment: That’s right. For my part, I’d accept that as a solution to this problem, but perhaps they want you to work through the details, too.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, I'd also like to ask if possible about the next question I am unsure on relating to this ellipse: If a point P on the ellipse has a distance $1/2$ from the origin, what is its distance from the other focus? I initially thought it was to simply use d1+d2=2a but found out this was wrong. My second attempt was to try and work out coordinates for P where I got $(0,1/2)$ and $(0,-1/2)$ therefore giving a distance of 5/6 from the other focus. However I do not think this is right as I got complex solutions along the way which I just ignored.. wondered if there was another way?