# Calculating the distance from a point on an ellipse and focal points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

An ellipse has the equation $$\frac{(x-\tfrac{1}{3})^2}{\tfrac{4}{9}}+\frac{y^2}{\tfrac{1}{3}}=1\;,$$

with focal points $(0,0)$ and $(2/3,0)$.

If a point P on the ellipse has a distance $1/2$
 from the origin, what is its distance from the other focus? I initially thought it was to simply use $d_1+d_2=2a$ but found out this was wrong. My second attempt was to try and work out coordinates for P where I got  $(0,1/2)$
 and $(0,−1/2)$
 therefore giving a distance of $5/6$ from the other focus. However I do not think this is right as I got complex solutions along the way which I just ignored.. wondered if there was another way?

Comment: We have $PF_1+PF_2=2a=2(2/3)=4/3$ where $F_1(0,0),F_2(2/3,0)$. So, the answer is $4/3-1/2=5/6$.

Comment: You should say that it is the same ellipse you had already considered some days ago in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2015222). This information can be beneficial to people in order to spare them time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there is some educational reason why you're not supposed to use
the formula $d_1+d_2=2a$.
That formula gives the correct result for good reasons.

The method in which you solve two simultaneous quadratic equations
is legitimate; after eliminating $y$, we can show that $x(x-2)=0$.
If we allow complex solutions, this leads to four solutions;
but since the points on the ellipse have real coordinates,
it is perfectly legitimate to discard the complex solutions.
The fact that $x$ and $y$ must be real is simply a constraint on the
solution space; you can even add it to your system of equations as follows:
\begin{gather}
\tfrac94(x-x_0)^2 + 3y^2 = 1,\\
x^2 + y^2 = 1,\\
\Im (x) = 0,\\
\Im (y) = 0.
\end{gather}
The last two equations simply say that $x$ and $y$ have zero imaginary parts.

---

Another technique is to convert the equation of the ellipse to
polar coordinates. The ellipse equation you were given was in the
general form
$$
\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1
$$
for positive $a$ and $b$,
where in this particular case $x_0=\frac13$, $y_0=0$, $a=\frac23$,
and $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.
Since $\frac23 > \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, the length of the semi-major axis is $a$.
In polar coordinates, the general equation for an ellipse with
semi-major axis $a$, semi-minor axis $b$,
one focus at $(0,0)$, and the other focus on the positive $x$-axis,
like this ellipse, is
$$
r = \frac{a(1 - e^2)}{1 - e\cos\theta}
$$
where $e = \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac ba\right)^2}$.
Plugging in  $a=\frac23$ and $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$, we find that
$e = \sqrt{1 - \frac34} = \frac12$, so the equation of this
particular ellipse comes out to
$$
r = \frac{\frac23\left(1 - \left(\frac12\right)^2\right)}
         {1 - \frac12\cos\theta}
  = \frac{1}{2 - \cos\theta}.
$$
But since $r$ in this equation is simply the distance from $(0,0)$
to a point on the ellipse at angle $\theta$ counterclockwise from
the positive $x$-axis, and the desired point $P$ is at distance
$\frac12$ from $(0,0)$, the polar coordinates of $P$ must satisfy
$$
\frac12 = \frac{1}{2 - \cos\theta},
$$
from which we can deduce that $\cos\theta = 0$, 
and therefore $\sin\theta = \pm 1$.
Converting the polar coordinates back into $x,y$ coordinates gives us
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos\theta = 0,\\
y &= r \sin\theta = \pm\frac12.
\end{align}
Therefore $P = \left(0,\frac12\right)$ or $P = \left(0,-\frac12\right)$.